# Get the last row from every year using mysql query

Tags: mysql

I need to get the row where the due_date field has the last month in every year.
For eg: if I have 3 entries with due_date field like 2014-5-21,2014-6-21,2014-7-21
I need the last row in year 2014, that will be 2014-7-21, like wise in 2015 and the following years.
Can someone help me out with this.
I tried but nothing worked out

```
SELECT distinct(year(due_date)) FROM `vw_mortgage_repayment_schedule_org` 
where mortgage_id ='AREM-1408614735-VLASFAQ8VI'
and month(due_date) = max(month())
```

I need all the last rows for the given mortgage of every year eg- 2014,2015,2016 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you `group by` the year of the `due_date`, that might just about give you what you need, given that we search for the `max` month in the select, and group by the year. Possibly. Can we have your table structure?

```
SELECT year(due_date), month(max(due_date)), max(due_date)
FROM `vw_mortgage_repayment_schedule_org` 
where mortgage_id ='AREM-1408614735-VLASFAQ8VI'
GROUP BY year(due_date)
```

Comment: What with dates `2014-07-21` and `2014-07-22`?

Comment: Well, if you just wanted the max month and nothing else, it would've be sufficient, however, I have adjusted to get the max month from the very last date as well.